# sql merge two select query results, keep result from query A if there is a conflict on one column's value

Tags: sql, postgresql

result set 1:

```
id  | animal
1   | panda
2   | duck
```

result set 2:

```
id  | animal
1   | horse
3   | dog
```

desired result after merge

```
id  | animal
1   | panda
2   | duck 
3   | dog
```

**is there a better way than check if the id exists in first when select the 2nd?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `not exists`:

```
select t1.id, t1.animal
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.id, t2.animal
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id);
```

It would be interesting to compare the performance of this with the performance of the `full join` version.  The [explain plans](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=645ed45528bfa2bd5dbdaca20083e041) of the two methods are surprisingly interesting.

Without any primary keys on the tables, this version is much, much faster than the `full join` version.  With primary keys, the `full join` is a bit faster.  In both cases, the `union all` should be faster for returning the *first* row.

What I don't understand is that the plan for the `not exists` version without primary keys is *faster* than the version with primary keys.  The mysteries of database optimizers.

Comment: Did you run this multiple times with different data as well. It should be the case that the random selection without primary keys giving the first record because theres no little load of indexing to start as with primary keys in random selection

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `full join` and `coalesce()` for priorization:

```
select id, coalesce(t1.animal, t2.animal) animal
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2 
     using (id)
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thank you... I think my mind was not quite there at that time!

Answer (score 0):

Just union all the two first then group by having count() >1

```
    Select * from(  Select distinct id, 
       animal from table
      Union all
     Select distinct id, animal from table) 
    Group by id, animal having count(*) 
     >1;
```